# Android gradient color - incorrect result

Tags: android, colors, gradient

I want to create a background of repeating images and over it add a gradient from white to transparent. So, it should start as full white at the top of the view then end like  completely transparent at the bottom, where the background images is completely seen.
My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <bitmap 
        android:dither="true" 
        android:src="@drawable/bg" 
        android:tileMode="repeat" >
    </bitmap>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient 
            android:angle="90" 
            android:endColor="#ffffffff" 
            android:startColor="#00000000" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

The problem is that I don't get a gradient from white (*#ffffff*) to transparent but a gray one to transparent. With a color picker I get the code of the *endColor* and it is #dfdfdf.

Why is this going wrong? Thanks!

ScreenShoot: [image]

*Specification*

I use this background in a style:

```
<resources>
<style name="Theme.NoBackground" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>"
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Can you post a screeenshot of the actual result? Maybe it can help...

Comment: Done. It seems like the gradient is repeating somehow

Comment: Why so many numerals in the hex code? I don't know if it makes a difference or if it matters...

Comment: Not that this will solve you problem, but you probably want your gradient between #FFFFFFFF and #00FFFFFF

Comment: @nmagerko the first two are alpha, the next 2 R, then g, b

Comment: Thanks JRaymond. That was the trick. Thanks to all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your gradient runs from transparent black to opaque white.

Don't you need this?

```
android:endColor="#ffffffff" 
android:startColor="#00ffffff" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue with having the gray shadow (when gradient other than black is used). The way i got around it is to change the alpha on the colour to be used for the gradient.

```
public static int alpha(int color, int alpha)
{
    return Color.argb(alpha,
            Color.red(color),
            Color.green(color),
            Color.blue(color));
}
```

You can also reduce the size of the gradient by passing the colour with an alpha of 0 in to the array multiple times

```
colour = alpha(color, 0XFF);
int gradientColor = alpha(color, 0X00); 
GradientDrawable shadow = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
    new int[]{color, gradientColor, gradientColor, gradientColor});
```